# Order by and return count of related model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


class users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userEmail = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPhone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPass = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userPass):

        self.userName = userName
        self.userEmail = userEmail
        self.userPhone = userPhone
        self.userPass = userPass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.userName, self.userEmail, self.userPhone)


class friendships(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    userR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.user_id')
    friendR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.friend_id)


class bestFriends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.user_id')
    best_friend = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.best_friend_id')

    def __init__(self, user_id, best_friend_id):

        self.user_id = user_id
        self.best_friend_id = best_friend_id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.best_friend_id)
```

I have a query that lists all the users and orders them by number of friends they have:

```
userList = users.query.join(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id).group_by(users.id).order_by(db.func.count(friendships.user_id).desc()).paginate(page, 10, False)
```

This query gives me the following object:

```
users.id | users.userName | users.userEmail | users.userPhone
```

I would like to get the count as a column  as well, like this:

```
users.id | users.userName | users.userEmail | users.userPhone | totalFriends
```

I don't want to use `db.session` because I want to use `.paginate` from `Model.query`.  How do I construct this query?

Comment: @van  -Thanks for pointing that out. It is very similar to my working query but doesn't use the count as a column, it only uses count for ordering

Comment: If you pay attention to the answer of the question we think yours is a duplicate of, you will notice that what you need to do is to simply add that `count` to the result list of your query. To achieve this just replace `userList = users.query.join(...` in your query with `userList = db.session.query(users, db.func.count(friendships.user_id)).join(...`

Comment: @van thank you for replying. I am aware of how to build the query with db.session......But as I said I wanna use .paginate(). Thats why I was using and need to use BaseQuery. Or alternatively a way of paginating db.session

Comment: Understood. First of all, you are very unclear in your question originally. If you really need to use `BaseQuery` then do the following `userList = users.query.add_column(db.func.count(friendships.user_id).label("num_friends").join(...`. Also I suggest replacing `join` with `outerjoin` in order to to skip users with no friends, unless you really do not want those.

Comment: @van Thank you for that it was useful. I wasn't sure how to  and where to use the .label(). Thanks again and sorry for not being clear to everyone.

Comment: Note that the result of the last query would be list of tuples `(users, int)`, so your client side view might need to be updated accordingly. If you want to make the `num_friends` a property of `users`, you can use [`column_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property)

Comment: Thanks @van. I got this query working properly both with db.session and BaseQuery. I did post a new question which takes this query further with a second outerjoin on it. I am having issues on how to target the last value I need. If you could take a look I would appreciate it a lot. Thanks again(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115356/build-model-query-of-a-related-model)