# Build Model.query of a related model

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to build a query that lists all the users, there best friend and there total number of friends. The list has to be ordered by totalFriends a user has.

I want the resulting query to have the following structure:

```
users.id | users.userName | users.userEmail | users.userPhone | totalFriends | bestFriends.userName | bestFriends.user_id
```

Example:

```
1 | Alex   | alex@alex.com     | 900102030 | 2 | Carlos | 2
2 | Carlos | carlos@carlos.com | 900102030 | 1 | Alex   | 1
3 | Sara   | sara@sara.com     | 900102030 | 1 | None   | None
4 | Jack   | jack@jack.com     | 900102030 | 0 | None   | None
```

This is my model:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class users(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userEmail = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPhone = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    userPass = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)



    def __init__(self, userName, userEmail, userPhone, userPass):

        self.userName = userName
        self.userEmail = userEmail
        self.userPhone = userPhone
        self.userPass = userPass

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.id, self.userName, self.userEmail, self.userPhone)




class friendships(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)


    userR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.user_id')
    friendR = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='friendships.friend_id')


    def __init__(self, user_id, friend_id):


        self.user_id = user_id
        self.friend_id = friend_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.friend_id)



class bestFriends(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.user_id')
    best_friend = db.relationship('users', foreign_keys='bestFriends.best_friend_id')


    def __init__(self, user_id, best_friend_id):

        self.user_id = user_id
        self.best_friend_id = best_friend_id


    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.user_id, self.best_friend_id)
```

I don't want to use db.session because I want to use .paginate from Model.query. How do I construct this query?

I have built a query that gathers the structure I want but without the bestFriends name which I do need:

```
userList = users.query.add_columns(bestFriends.best_friend_id, db.func.count(friendships.user_id).label("total")).outerjoin(friendships, users.id==friendships.user_id).group_by(users.id).outerjoin(bestFriends, users.id==bestFriends.user_id).order_by(db.func.count(friendships.user_id).desc()).paginate(page, 5, false)
```

This allows me the following on the jinja side:

```
<div id="innerContent">
{% if userList.items %}
     {% for user in userList.items %}
            <div class="contentUsers">
                {{ user.users.userName }}|{{ user.total }}|{{ user.best_friend_id }}
```

Which gives:

```
id|  name  |Number friends| best friend id when exists 
1 | Alex   | 2            |  2                         
2 | Carlos | 1            |  1
3 | Sara   | 1            |
4 | Jack   | 0            |
```

How do I target bestFriends.userName?

Comment: Why do you use `bestfriends` table if there can be only one best friend?

Comment: I thought it be more organized to separate friendships and bestFriends into two tables rather than add an extra column to friendships table. Is that less efficient?

Comment: I would add a `best_friend_id` to the `users` table

Comment: hmmm I see...just thinking that it is the last query I had left. I would have to make many changes on the rest of the project. I'll definitely consider changing it. Is it messy to go around the query result I need as the tables stand now?

Comment: At least define relationship as in my answer with `uselist=False` on both sides so it is easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added relationship to your model as below:

```
class users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    friends = association_proxy(
        '_friends', 'friend',
        creator=lambda v: friendships(friend=v),
    )

    best_friend = db.relationship(
        'users',
        secondary='BestFriends',
        primaryjoin='users.id==bestFriends.user_id',
        secondaryjoin='users.id==bestFriends.best_friend_id',
        uselist=False,
        backref=db.backref('best_friend_of', uselist=False),
    )


class friendships(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Friendships"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)

    user = db.relationship(users, foreign_keys=user_id, backref='_friends')
    friend = db.relationship(users, foreign_keys=friend_id)


class bestFriends(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "BestFriends"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'), nullable=False)
    best_friend_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Users.id'))
```

Added some test data:

```
# add data
u1, u2, u3, u4 = _users = [
    users(userName=_un)
    for _un in ('Alex', 'Carlos', 'Sara', 'Jack')
]
u1.friends.append(u2)
u1.friends.append(u3)
u2.friends.append(u4)
u3.friends.append(u1)

u1.best_friend = u2
u2.best_friend = u1
db.session.add_all(_users)
db.session.commit()
```

After that getting the query is pretty easy:

```
# create query
user_bf = db.aliased(users, name='user_bf')
userList = (
    users.query
    .add_column(db.func.count(friendships.user_id).label("total"))
    .add_column(user_bf.id.label("best_friend"))
    .add_column(user_bf.userName.label("best_friend_name"))
    .outerjoin(friendships, users.id == friendships.user_id)
    .outerjoin(user_bf, users.best_friend)
    .group_by(users.id)
    .order_by(db.func.count(friendships.user_id).desc())
    .paginate(1, 10, False)
)
for user in userList.items:
    print(user)
```

But I would probably remove the table for best friend and add it directly to the `users` table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear answer. Learned very much from it. I can see your point. It does not seem worth it to complicate the model that much fore only one query. I will remove the best friend table and add a column to users table. How would you go around that case relationship and query wise?