# SQLAlchemy bidirectional one to one relationship with self

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a bidirectional one to one relationship on my User model with SQLAlchemy. I need it to link two users as partners, such that if I query for a user I should get his/her partner (which is obviously another user), and viceversa. So I have this class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
```

and I would like to have something like this:

```
first_user = User.query.first()
second_user = first_user.partner

print(second_user.partner is first_user)
> True
```

Is that doable? And how?
Thanks everybody.

Comment: Everything is doable, but it is not something offered either by the databases or by sqlalchemy, and therefore the way to do it depends on the other specific requirements and which limitations are you ready to accept.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115356/build-model-query-of-a-related-model).
It might be sufficient to add `partner_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('user.id'))` and relationship `partner = db.relationship('User', uselist=False, backref='partner_of')`. Ensuring items are in sync is a different matter completely, but you need to be more specific.